# How to read Application URL in startup class particularly in "ConfigureService" method in .net core 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am able to read URL in **Configure** method in startup class with help of middleware but I need to read URL in "**ConfigureService**" method which I am not getting any solution as of now.  Is there any way to read application URL in "**ConfigureService**" method?

Comment: If you need help making code work that you wrote, it helps to show relevant code, such as how you get the URL in the Configure() method. [Edit] your question to add it.

Answer (score 1):

The URL that the web server listens on does not have to be the URL you want it to think it's on. It could be proxied.

You can't get the request pipeline in ConfigureServices, as the pipeline isn't even ready there.

The code at that point also doesn't have to be woken up from an external request, could be app pool initialization or a monitoring application.

Put the site URL in your appsettings, read it from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but I have to decide to set one  property based on application URL over there. Yes as you said, I have read url from appsettings but decision should be taken based on application url whether it should call test or acceptable or production appsettings value. To put it in nutshell, I am looking the way to read application URL there but as your explanation it looked like impossible. Is there any tricks that can be implemented to find this?

Comment: Those values should have the same key, but a different value per environment.